# the proof of variational principal for the principal eigenvalue (checking orthonormal subset)

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, orthonormal, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Hi I am looking at part 3 of the proof in Evans Chapter 6. 
I have difficulty understanding 
"Furthermore from (6) and (7) we see that $(\lambda_k^{-1/2} w_k)$ is an orthonormal subset of $H_0^1(U)$. It is known, from the previous results of the chapter, $(w_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis of $L^2(U)$, $w_k\in H_0^1(U)$ is an eigenfunction corresponding to $\lambda_k.$

The bilinear form is defined as 
$$ B[u,v]:=\int_{U} a^{ij} D^j u D^i v+b^i D^i u v+cuv .$$ Given $u$ is a weak solution, the following also holds for the eigenvalue problem
$$ B[u,v]=(\lambda u,v)\,\,\,\forall\,\,\,v\in H_0^1(U)$$
I understand this is really a matter of checking definition. My confusions two-fold. I do not see, by diving $w_k$ by $\lambda_k^{1/2},$

1) Why we get an orthonormal subset? This means??
2) Why this orthonormal subset is in $H_0^1(U)?$

Now the most **important** questions of mine.

**A**. It is true that $(w_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ forms an orthogonal basis of $H_0^1(U)$, in view of the Galerkin approximation of weak solutions in Chapt 7. How to verify this?

**B**. In view of the proof below, $(w_k)_{k=1}^{\infty}$ cannot be orthonormal basis of $H_0^1(U).$ (Though the scaled version does.) Can someone give a proof, perhaps a contradictory argument?

I am looking for a proof that make use of the definition of $H_0^1$ inner product and integration by parts, rather than inferring from (6) and (7).

[image]

Comment: What's $B$?${}{}{}$

Comment: @JohnMa See edited. Would you be able to provide an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous theorem (on page 355) shows that $w_k \in H^1_0(U)$. Identities $(6)$ and $(7)$ tell you that $\{ w_k \}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthogonal collection and the length of each $w_k$ with respect to $B$ is $||w_k||_{B} = \sqrt{B[w_k,w_k]} = \sqrt{\lambda_k}$. Thus, if we normalize $w_k$ we get an **orthonormal** collection of elements in $H^1_0(U)$ with respect to $B$.

Comment: I cannot understand why $\|w_k\|_B=\sqrt{B[w_k,w_k]}.$ There is no where in the original proof states so.

Comment: You wrote yourself that $B[u,v] = \lambda(u,v)$ when $u$ is an eigenfunction. If you plug $u = v = w_k$, you get $B[w_k,w_k] = \lambda_k(w_k, w_k) = \lambda_k$ (since $w_k$ are $L^2$-orthonormal).

Comment: Of course I know this. Base on what you wrote, we then have $\sqrt{B[w_k,w_k]}=\lambda_k^{1/2}\|w_k\|=\lambda_k^{1/2}$. Then $B[\frac{w_k}{\lambda_k^{1/2}},\frac{w_k}{\lambda_k^{1/2}}]=(\lambda_k\frac{w_k}{\lambda_k^{1/2}},\frac{w_k}{\lambda_k^{1/2}})=\lambda_k\frac{1}{\lambda_k}\|w\|_L^2=1$. Yes it is a orthonormal subset of something. But, how could this turn out to be that of $H_0^1?$

Comment: By the way, I edited my question and hope what I really confused about can be resolved.

Comment: I don't really understand what you don't understand... maybe what confuses you is that the $w_k$ is not an orthonormal basis with respect to the standard norm on $H^1_0(U)$ but with respect to the norm on $H^1_0(U)$ induced by $B$.

Comment: yes. kind of, the fact that $w_k$ is not an o.n.b. on $H_0^1(U)$ in usual sense, but rather an o.n.b. on $H_0^1$ induced by $B.$ This sort of things cannot be found in standard functional analysis text...